# SQL query according to combobox in Java

Tags: java, sql, swing, variables, combobox

```
final JComboBox destination= new JComboBox();
destination.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"city1", "city2", "city3"}));
destination.setBounds(413, 11, 147, 20);
int selectedIndex1=destination.getSelectedIndex();
contentPane.add(destination);
```

and

```
final JComboBox departure= new JComboBox();
departure.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"city1", "city2", "city3"}));
departure.setBounds(413, 11, 147, 20);
int selectedIndex1=departure.getSelectedIndex();
contentPane.add(departure);
```

I am coding a bus reservation system for my homework but I can't write a correct SQL query with Java.

And I have 3 comboboxes.

I want to write a SQL query to display available buses with their times. I mean something like this:

```
select busid,bustime
from table1
where des=destination.getSelectedItem()
   && dep=departure.getSelectedItem()
   && date=date.getSelectedItem()
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: A couple things up-front: first, in SQL && should be AND, secondly SQL is a string which means you need to derive it. `"SELECT fields... FROM table WHERE field1 = :parameter1 AND field2 = :parameter2 etc..."` The java tutorials have a good walk-through for the ComboBoxModel but you need to create a functioning query first.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take the time to read through the [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) trail...

Your query would still need to be "quoted" properly

```
String query = "select busid,bustime from table1 where des='" + destination.getSelectedItem() + "' AND dep='" + departure.getSelectedItem() + "' AND date='" + date.getSelectedItem() + '";
```

It's begin a while, but I don't recall `&&` been a valid operator in SQL...

Of course, you really should use a prepared statement

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try {
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("select busid,bustime from table1 where des=? AND dep=? AND date=?");
    stmt.setString(1, destination.getSelectedItem());
    stmt.setString(2, departure.getSelectedItem());
    // I'm assuming this is String, but it could be a Date
    stmt.setString(3, date.getSelectedItem());

    stmt.execute();
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        stmt.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```